# how to redesign the permission dialog window for caapturing the screen?

Tags: android

I want to share my screen to other device.

and I have to createScreenCaptureIntent to create dialog window to ask for permisson
then how to design the dialog to fit my theme of the APP?

Comment: share more information and image if possible

Comment: That is not your dialog. It is the operating system's dialog. It is not supposed to fit your theme.

Comment: then how to share my screen to my computer in my APP in your opinion?@CommonsWare